# Apache mod rewrite for dynamic pages

Tags: php, regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite

I'm having a problem with my mod rewrite rule that I wrote for my website, nothing seems to change as my pages URL are loading the same as before, if anyone could have a look at it and let me know if there is any problems it would be very much appreciated, thanks!

**REWRITE RULE**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?art_id=$1 [L]
```

**URL**

```
http://www.test.com/index.php?art_slug=test
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
http://www.test.com/test
```

Comment: did you intend for your get parameter to go from art_slug to art_id, also one of the more common problems is ensuring that .htaccess is being processed at all, try putting some garbage text at the top of your .htaccess file if you .htaccess is being processed then you should get a 500 error from the server.

Comment: @Orangepill god I feel like an idiot right now, hahaha the rewrite rule should obviously be `art_slug` not `art_id` I don't know why I put id haha anyways thanks, that will most likely fix my problem as my .htaccess works find as I have a new redirects before that code which work no problem, but thanks for making me look over that code again haha

Comment: What's "dynmatic". Is that like "dynamic"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# to externally redirect from /index.php?art_slug=test to /art_slug/test
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+/(?:index\.php|)\?([^=]+)=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

# to internally forward from /art_slug/test to /index.php?art_slug=test
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /index.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks, I used that and now what is happening is if I type the url `www.test.com/test` it works but if I type in `www.test.com?art_slug=test` the url stays as `www.test.com?art_slug=test`, thanks for all your help!

Comment: So would I just do my links like this now instead? `<a href="/test">Link</a>`

Comment: Its better to to keep URL as `/test` but other rule is failing because you have `http://www.test.com/?art_slug=test` instead of `http://www.test.com/index.php?art_slug=test`

Comment: Awesome thanks for the clarifying that for me! Also for my URL is it possible to do something like `www.test.com/art_slug/test` or should I just leave it at `www.test.com/test`, thanks again!

Comment: I think for seo purpose `www.test.com/art_slug/test` would be better. However this will require some modifications in .htaccess code above, let me know if you want me to edit my answer for this.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking and if you don't mind could you? It would be very much appreciated, thanks again!

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The only problem I'm running into now is when I use the updated version its not loading my CSS style sheets anymore, thanks again!

Comment: I will be going offline for few hrs. For css, js, images etc make sure to use absolute path that starts with either `/` or `http://`

Comment: Awesome thanks, sorry I'm used to working on localhost not on an actual server, thanks again that's all the help I needed, you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?art_id=$1 [L]
```

Should work. `:)`

Comment: Are you sure your server support mod_rewrite? Have you checked that?

Comment: I believe so as I have another rewrite rule that's redirecting domains to 1 domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)/$ search.php?keyword=$1
```

Should work. :)